# Images moving from left to right animation on regular interval of time and periodically?

Tags: android, android-animation

i have more than 10 images that comes from a server. I have to show them in animation way like moving from left to right one after another repeatedly. By using Animation Drawable API i can achieve this. but i can't get moving animation. Is there any way to solve this problem?
FYI recently google play store implemented this. I need the same feature that showing here.
[image]

Comment: Why dont you prefer viewpager.

Comment: Okay i will try with view pager

Comment: https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager try this once it works.